# Touchpad rough scrolling in version 13.1 linux?

Tags: front-end, version-13.1

I changed from windows to linux (arch linux, endeavouros, kde, x11 (but wayland was not better)) and simultaneously from version 13 to version 13.1 and the scrolling is rather difficult with the touch-pad. It feels like the touch-pad has low sensitivity and I have to push over long lengths to make a nudge. 3 out of 5 gestures do not seem to have any real effect. Scrolling with the mouse wheel seems alright.

Everywhere else on my laptop (firefox, editor, pdf (although okular is a bit slow)) scrolling seems alright.

I am not sure if this is a linux problem or a mathematica problem as I changed both the mathematica version and the os.

Has anyone else experienced this ?

Comment: Similar issue here on Ubuntu 22.04 with Mathematica 13.1. I need to put the mouse pointer in the small scroll bar at the right of the window to be able to scroll with the scroll wheel of my mouse. With previous versions of Mathematica, scroll wheel worked everywhere.

Comment: @BertRAMAert, in my case it is the touchpad that is hard to work with. With the scroll wheel it seems to be alright

Comment: I work in Fedora 36, and have problems in Mathematica 13.1 with BOTH the mouse wheel and the touchpad. Can only scroll when pointing at the scroll bar. I also have Mathematica 10.3 installed, and scrolling works normally there.

Comment: @BertRAMAerts, thanks! Now I can at least scroll again with your tip. Still, a very annoying crazy bug.

Comment: exactly same issue here, ubuntu 20.04, Dell XPS 15. Most of the scroll commands seem not to arrive at the front end. Every other program is perfectly fine. Will report to Wolfram Support, I suggest everyone who encounters this to do the same. They're usually quick to fix stupid stuff like this.

Comment: @MatthiasKoenig I tried reporting a bug once but I did not understand the website.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in 13.2. Does disabling xinput work around the issue?

```
QT_XCB_NO_XI2_MOUSE=1 Mathematica
```

Comment: I suppose you propose to start Mathematica from the linux command line as in
bert@legion5ubuntu:~$ QT_XCB_NO_XI2_MOUSE=1 Mathematica
This does not solve my issue. I still need to put the mouse pointer in the small scroll bar at the right of the window to be able to scroll with the scroll wheel of my mouse.

Comment: This does not help me either.

Comment: Version 13.2 is not yet available right?

Comment: Mathematica 13.2 was released today.
I installed it and mouse wheel scrolling works fine now with X11 as window system.

Comment: This got upvotes. Did it help anyone? Or is this getting upvotes because it is fixed in 13.2 (which indeed it is, I can now confirm). Might be best to separate those answers as I don't believe there is any evidence that the work around works.

Answer (score 1):

I now have Ubuntu 22.10 beta with nVIDIA driver 520.56.06.
When I use X11 as window system, I have above described scroll issue.
But... when I use Wayland as window system, scrolling works normal.

Answer (score 1):

Still having this issue with Mathematica 12, but for me helps turning on the option

> Natural Scrolling. Scrolling moves the content, not the view.

which is available in **System preferences** under the **Mouse & Touchpad** settings. It depends on the touchpad, you may try to use the Edge scrolling option instead of the two-fingers scrolling.